# pandas conditional assignment to multiple columns using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas version `1.0.5`

I have a following dataframe:

```
test = {'Price': ['Free','free', '-16.66', 'Name', '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
df.loc[df['Price'].astype(str).str.contains(':'), ['col_1', 'col_2']] = df['Price'].astype(str).str.split(':',1,expand=True)
```

Here in this e.g. if value contains `:` then I need to split the values and need to assign two parts to two new cols `col_1` and `col_2` respectively.

But I get this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['col_1', 'col_2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I tried without `.loc`

```
df[df['Price'].astype(str).str.contains(':'), ['col_1', 'col_2']] = df['Price'].astype(str).str.split(':',1,expand=True)
```

And got this error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me working well

Comment: @jezrael `1.0.5`

Comment: It is old version, try upgrade.

Comment: it is version from 2020-06-17, latest is 1.3.4

Comment: Don't use loc. Try to just use df['Price'].astype(str).str.split(':',1,expand = True)

Comment: @GedasMiksenas I have updated the post regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not possible upgrade create columns with empty values:

```
df = df.assign(col_1=np.nan, col_2=np.nan)

df.loc[df['Price'].astype(str).str.contains(':'), ['col_1', 'col_2']] = df['Price'].astype(str).str.split(':',1,expand=True)
```

Another idea, thanks @azro working for me if there is at least one value with `:`:

```
df[['col_1', 'col_2']] = df['Price'].astype(str).str.split(':',1,expand=True)
```

Comment: does something like `df[['col_1', 'col_2']] = df['Price'].astype(str).str.split(':',1,expand=True)` may work ? I don't know if there is that kind of syntax, like unpacking

Comment: @azro - hmm, it should working, because append DF, not sure about ol pandad version. But add to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :)

```
test = {'Price': ['Free','free', '-16.66', 'Name', '', "what:yes"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
df[['one', 'two']] = df['Price'].astype(str).str.split(':',1,expand = True)
df.fillna('')
```

Output:

```
    Price       one     two
0   Free        Free    
1   free        free    
2   -16.66      -16.66  
3   Name        Name    
4           
5   what:yes    what    yes
```